# Center a programmatically created radio button in its linear layout vertical parent Android

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, android-linearlayout, center

I am creating a linear layout programmatically with orientation = vertical.
In that linear layout I am also creating 2 or 3 objects programmatically:

1-Image view

2-Text View (I create this object if it is needed)

3-Radio button

By problem is how I can center the radio button in its parent ?

---

edit:
My code is in Xamarin.Android C# but I think it is easy to covert it to Java Android

```
                    LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this)
                    {
                        Orientation = Orientation.Vertical

                    };


                    LinearLayout sub1LinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this)
                    {
                        //Set orientation = horizontal
                        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal

                    };

                    //Add the sub1LinearLayout to the mainLinearLayout
                    mainLinearLayout.AddView(sub1LinearLayout);


                    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                    {


                        LinearLayout sub2LinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this)
                        {
                            Orientation = Orientation.Vertical
                        };


                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
                            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);



                        RadioButton Box = new RadioButton(this){
                           //Set gravity = center
                              Gravity = GravityFlags.Center
                         };



                            switch (SomeMode)
                            {


                                //Show radio button + image
                                case Mode.ShowBoxAndImage:
                                {

                                    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);


                                    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path);


                                    image.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


                                    sub2LinearLayout.AddView(image);


                                    layoutParams.SetMargins(padding, 0, 2 * padding, 0);

                                   break;
                                }
                                //Show radio button + its text + image
                                case Mode.ShowBoxAndImageAndText:
                                {
                                    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);


                                    Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path);


                                    image.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


                                    sub2LinearLayout.AddView(image);


                                    TextView Name = new TextView(this)
                                    {

                                        Text = name,


                                        TextSize = nameTextSize,

                                        //Set gravity = center
                                        Gravity = GravityFlags.Center
                                    };


                                    Name.SetTextColor(new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.colorBlack)));

                                    sub2LinearLayout.AddView(Name);


                                    layoutParams.SetMargins(padding, 0, 2 * padding, 0);

                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                    }


                            sub2LinearLayout.AddView(Box);


                            sub2LinearLayout.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;


                            sub1LinearLayout.AddView(sub2LinearLayout);

                            //Set sub2LinearLayout gravity = bottom
                            sub2LinearLayout.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Bottom);
```

[image]

Comment: provide your xml code

Comment: where is your xml?

Comment: I am creating every thing programmatically, there is no xml here

Comment: Have you set `Gravity.CENTER` for it ?

Comment: try it once with set Gravity programmatically yourView.setGravity(Center)

Comment: I have tried setting the gravity = center for both the linear layout and the radio button but it did not help

Comment: Set gravity to radiobutton same as you've set to textview in your code

Comment: I tried to set the gravity = center to my radio button but it did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating LayoutParams for every view and add it with its view to the parent linear layout.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams center = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
                                    {
                                        Gravity = GravityFlags.Center
                                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Use layout gravity in all **child views**

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Comment: OP can't. Because he is adding views dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
yourLinearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Check if this is working or not.

Comment: I have tried setting the gravity = center for both the linear layout and the radio button but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

yourview.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I have tried this one, well all view were in center but the image view has been resized to a smaller size !

Comment: As i can see in your code you set the gravity in your textview. On the screenshot we can see that the textview is centered. You didn't add the gravity to the radiobutton (Box in your case) at all. Try to add gravity to the radiobutton too.

Comment: I tried to set the gravity = center to my radio button but it did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    linearLayout.setPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
    setContentView(linearLayout);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.english);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setText("1");

    RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
    button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    button.setChecked(true);

    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.addView(button);
}
```

[image: Screenshot]